# How to read 他 in this sentence?

Tags: readings

In Instagram, there is a activity notification that is

> aさん、bさん、他2人があなたをフォローし始めた。

Is 他 read as "ほか" or is there another way to read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is 他{ほか}. The other pronunciations of 他 more commonly appear in multi-character/compound words.

Comment: Thank you. In Google translate says that it's 他{た}, so I was in doubt.

Comment: The た reading is sometimes used on its own formal contexts

Comment: @Angelos Thus "mostly". But I take your point. I am going to further qualify it.

Comment: Formality affecting た / ほか readings applies not only to compound words, but also to common constructs such as その他.

Comment: @Will Another good point! Noted. To be honest, I only added the second sentence without much detail because the first sentence alone didn't meet the character requirement for answers.